# iOS Firebase chat application customisation

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a requirement that using firebase to develop chat application, when ever the user post a video in the group or sent video to another user. The admin has to approve it to publish the video. Is it possible using firebase.

Comment: Yes everything is possible.

Comment: https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, It is possible in ios as well as Android.